# Links are not working on All Plugins Page

Tags: links

I apologigize for the question, as it sounds silly.
But I am forced to ask this question, as I didn't find it's answer anywhere.

I have about 3 sites on WordPress, and 2 are working absolutely fine. But the 3rd one have some problem with links.

I mean, If I go to **All Plugins** page, and click on **Activate** or **Deactivate** or **Delete**, then nothing happens.

However if I copy the URL by mouse right clicking (and copying url), and visit after pasting it in browser, then it works properly.

I have WordPress 3.5.1 with theme twenty twelve on all sites. I have also tried changing theme and removing all plugins, but still the problem exists.

Can someone knows the resolution of this issue.

Comment: "clicking on **Activate** or **Deactivate** or **Delete**" - is that using the bulk actions or on a single plugin? Are there javascript errors showing in your browsers [error console](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors)? Do you have `WP_DEBUG` turned on, and if so, what does it report?

Comment: I apologize, how can I enable WP_DEBUG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps you can take to resolve this issue:

- Download Fresh Install of WordPress from Wordpress.org
- Deactivate All Plugins
- Deactivate Theme-Twenty Twelve and Try Activating some other Basic theme like Twenty Eleven
- Disable Browser Ad-Blocker Add-ons (if any)

Hopefully your problem will get solved by taking the above steps.

Comment: Thanks kumar, this worked.
I don't know which step worked exactly, but ultimately my problem has been resolved.